# Generating Radio propagation pattern in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I want to implement a part of article. The following explanations are expressed in it.
"we evaluate the performance of proposed localization method at varying degree of irregularity, where DOI defines the radio propagation irregularity per unit degree change in direction. The radio propagation irregularity model used in this paper is shown as follows:"

[image]

I have tried to write the code of this part but It doesn't work and can't get a result.

```
function Coeff=k(i)
Rand=rand(1,100);
DOI=0.02;
if(i==0)
Coeff=1;  %Terminating condition
else
     while i<360
      Coeff=k(i-1)+Rand*DOI;    %DOI=[0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05]
     end
end
end
```

And The following figure has been shown in that article for DOI=0.02...I need to get an output like this, How can I do it

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no question in this "question"!

Comment: Thanks for your comment,No I have question my code does not work and the figure is output of the article ... It's not mine. I need help for writing a code that works:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you post a link to the article, but in this case they just generate a circular path with some noise.

```
DOI=0.05;
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,360); %360 angles
r=-DOI+2*DOI*rand([1,360]); %random values between -DOI and DOI
r=cumsum(r)+1;              %add them to make a path, with mean value 1
while abs(r(end)-r(1))> DOI %start and finish must not be too far away from eachother
    r=-DOI+2*DOI*rand([1,360]);
    r=cumsum(r)+1;    
end
plot(r.*cos(phi),r.*sin(phi),'r',cos(phi),sin(phi),'--b')
axis equal
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/29cq4b1to0nybae/singh2015.pdf?dl=0                        Thanks a million @Gelliant , Actually the range  and shape of the figure is very important for me, I really appreciate your help if you can help me get more accurate result: The pages 9 and 10  are related to this part

Comment: dear Gelliant, May I ask you to review my Question...I couldn't get the exact result , I really need it for doing the rest of my project.

Comment: Dear Zein, You are aware that this is a process for generating a -random- circular path? You will never get the exact result back, because it is random.

Comment: In the paper they don't specify `Rand`. I presume it is a random value between 0 and 1. Therefore `±Rand*DOI` generates values in the interval `[-DOI..DOI]`. Also in their paper they start at 1 at an angle of 0, this is not correct IMHO. It should be `1±Rand*DOI`, because there is no reason to assume the range must be 1 at angle 0.